# Any issues for web3 on digital ocean?

Tags: web3js, metamask, dapps, digitalocean

My dapp which is currently testing on ropsten works perfectly when i run the frontend from local but dosent return addresses when i run on a digital ocean server. it is successfully connected to ropsten which i determined using a console log but it dosent return any  of the addresses so im guessing there is some issue with metamask or web3 with digital ocean.
Has anyone else come across the same?

Answer (score 0):

You account are only persisted in your local state and probably do not exist on Ropsten yet. If you have the account connected to metamask you can check

Comment: accounts are connected to metamask